# Разбор dll и добавление их в программу

Tags: c#, wpf, ресурсы, assembly

Есть программа, которая должна выполнять очень сложную функцию (прошу помочь в её реализации):

> Есть dll. В ней лежит текстовый файл с примерно такой структурой:

```
{
    MainWindow="MainWindow.xaml"
    Code="MainWindow.xaml.cs"
    Pattern=WPFStandart
}
```

> Запарсить я его смогу, но мне нужно как-то использовать окно с логикой, описанное в этой dll, причём dll должна лежать в папке с проектом, название у dll всегда разное (знаю как узнать его), и через Visual Studio в зависимости не добавишь, из-за названия и всегда разного содержимого (разрабы разные, а точнее их команды).

Вся информация изначально хранится внутри dll в файле pkginfo.txt, который лежит в корне с проектом (компилируется как внедряемый при сборке ресурс), желательно, чтобы окно открывалось без локального копирования ("разархивации длл-ки").

**Update**
Я нашёл способ с

```
[DllImport("name.dll")]
public static extern void VoidInDll();
```

Но у меня название открываемого DLL задаёт пользователь, а `DllImport` принимает только константы. 
Жду варианты...

Comment: Так, давайте попытаемся понять и разбить вашу задачу на части. (1) Есть текстовый файл. Из него нужно извлечь строки — это вам понятно, как делать? (2) Что означает «использовать окно, описанное в DLL»? Там есть класс с именем — имя известно? Если имя известно, можно создать экземпляр класса, и если это окно, то показать его — а что делать дальше?

Comment: @VladD 1. Да понятно, только текстовый файл находится внутри Dll, 2. В dll есть окно, название которого написано в этом txt, вызвать я его смогу, но основная задача - как-то нужно добавить этот dll.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Dll чужая, обычная, достать из файловой системы. Путь к файлу известен.

Comment: Понятно, что из файловой системы. Уточните, каким именно образом файл запихан внутрь DLL, так как есть разные способы. Это обычные ресурсы .NET-сборки или что-то другое?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, обычные ресурсы.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Обновил вопрос, чтобы было более понятно.

Comment: DllImport тут не причем. Смотрите в сторону классов System.Reflection.Assembly и ResourceReader (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx). Позже напишу подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, вопрос состоит из двух частей: как работать с ресурсами сборки, и как динамически работать с типами. Для решения данных задач используются классы `System.Reflection.Assembly` и `System.Activator`. Следующий упрощенный пример демонстрирует это.

Создадим тестовый проект библиотеки классов `ResTestDLL`, содержащий текстовый файл `file.txt`, отмеченный как внедренный ресурс, и класс:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ResTestDLL
{
    public class Cat
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "I am cat";
        }
    }
}
```

Создадим приложение:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace ResTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /**** Демонстрация загрузки ресурса *****/

            //путь к DLL
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ResTestDLL.dll");

            //имя ресурса: складывается из имени сборки и имени файла
            string resname = "ResTestDLL.file.txt";

            Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(path);//загружаем DLL

            string[] names = ass.GetManifestResourceNames();//получаем все ресурсы
            if (names.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: В сборке нет ресурсов");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            foreach (string name in names)
            {
                if (name == resname) //находим нужный ресурс
                {
                    //открываем поток для чтения данных
                    Stream s = ass.GetManifestResourceStream(name);                    
                    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(s);

                    using (read)
                    {
                        //выводим содержимое ресурса
                        Console.WriteLine(read.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

            /**** Демонстрация динамической работы с типами *****/

            string classname = "Cat"; //имя класса, который мы будем создавать
            string method = "ToString"; //имя вызываемого метода

            var types = ass.GetTypes(); //получаем все классы в сборке           

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.Name == classname)//находим нужный тип
                {
                    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);//создаем экземпляр

                    MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod(method);

                    string res = (string)mi.Invoke( //вызываем метод
                        o, //ссылка на экземпляр
                        new object[0] //массив аргументов
                        );

                    Console.WriteLine("Результат вызова метода: " + res);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();            

        }
    }
}
```

Cкомпилируем его, и поместим `DLL` в один каталог с `EXE`. Приложение должно вывести текст из файла `file.txt` и результат вызова метода.

**Примечание.** Если ресурс добавляется не как элемент проекта, а через вкладку "Ресурсы" в свойствах проекта, все будет несколько сложнее: придется использовать класс [ResourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx) и вытаскивать ресурсы из `dictionary`.

Comment: @Osid если метод ничего не возвращает, Invoke вернет null. Можно использовать переменную object, если вы не знаете заранее возвращаемый тип.